# Copying value from char[] into an integer

Tags: c

I have a txt file with the values:

1 -200 3 4

2 3 5 7

How do I get the length of the input (so that I can tell the code where to stop) and copy the values before the whitespace? ie I want a = 1, b = -200, c = 3, d = 4 (the methods I have attempted only seem to add value in the form of : -2 + 0 + 0 = -2)

The code I'm working on :

```
 char buffer[100];
 char c;
 int x = 0;
 while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){ // while stdin isn't empty
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){ // loop through integer i (need to change 
                                   //i < 10 to be size of the line)
         if (strchr(buffer, c) != NULL){ 
         // if there is a white space
         // add the value of buffer to x
            x += buffer[i] - '0';
         }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one, it doesn't have the constraint of adding 4 numbers:

```
char buffer[100], 
char bufferB[100]; //holds the individual numbers
int x = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
//you dont need a while in fgets, because it will never be NULL (the '\n' will always be read)
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL){
    while(buffer[i] != '\n' && buffer[i] != '\0'){
        //If we have not occured the white space store the character
        if( buffer[i] != ' ' ){
            bufferB[j] = buffer[i];

            j++;
        }
        else{ //we have found the white space so now make the string to an int and add to x
            bufferB[j] = '\0'; //make it a string

            x += atoi(bufferB);

            j = 0;
        }

        i++;
    }

    //The last number
    if( j != 0 ){
        bufferB[j] = '\0';

        x += atoi(bufferB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Although kind of confusing, hopefully I'll be able to work out the steps behind this through testing and print statements.
Thank you!

Comment: This code only reads one line; the original code read multiple lines.  I think the `while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != NULL)` loop is appropriate.